# Failed to load url when mocking window.URL

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vite, vitest

I am migrating a huge codebase from Create React App + Jest to Vite + Vitest.

I have some components that use `window.URL` that throws in test suites.
I have tried to mock it a bunch of ways, the below is the somewhat best way.

```js
if (!window.URL?.createObjectURL) {
    if (!window.URL) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        window.URL = {};
    }

    window.URL.createObjectURL = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return "URL";
    });
}
```

This will make the tests, that previously failed, pass, but it will print out this error on every second or third test that passes.

```
stderr | unknown test
Error: Failed to load url C:/code/frontend-ui/URL (resolved id: C:/code/project/URL). Does the file exist?
    at loadAndTransform (file:///C:/code/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:53376:21)
```

Anyone have an idea how to handle this?